# Вывести количество слов в листе stream api java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Имеется 2 стринговых листа: `List<String> fileList` и `List<String> arr`. Требуется вывести сколько слов в fileList содержатся в arr, сделал так:

```java
fileList
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> arr
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(s::equals)
    )
    .count();
```

Правильный ли такой подход? Или есть какой-то более лучший способ?

Comment: Обязательно ли нужно использовать Stream API? Если нет, то https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349369/list-intersection-in-java

Answer (score 8):

Быстрее и проще будет воспользоваться пересечением множеств:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(fileList);
set.retainAll(new HashSet<String>(arr));

int count = set.size();
```

А если уж использовать стримы, то не плодить их для каждого элемента. Эффективнее будет так:

```
long count = fileList.stream()
                     .filter(arr::contains)
                     .count();
```

Comment: +1 только множества дубликаты сожрут